# Как хранить объект aiogram.types.message в базе данных?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Мне надо чтобы сообщение пользователя сохранился куда нибудь и можно было его отправлять когда угодно.
Заметьте - НЕ текст, А сообщение. То есть если в сообщении фото или другие данные они тоже должны сохраняться.

Я хотел сохранить сообшение в бд sqlite как строку, а потом преобразовать его на aiogram.types.message.
Но текст не преобразовывается на сообщение:

```
from aiogram import types

@dp.message_handler()
async def abc(msg):
    to_save = str(msg) # Преобразовываю сообщение на строку чтобы сохранить его в бд
    saved_msg = types.Message(to_save) # Вот так я хотел преобразовать текст на сообщение обратно, но..
    await saved_msg.send_copy(msg.chat.id)
    print(saved_msg) # Сообщение не отправляется потому что saved_msg - ПУСТОЙ
```

Может преобразовать текст на сообщение нелзя, тогда как хранить сообщение по другому??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой и есть простое решение. Работаю с aiogram==2.25

В aiogram есть методы для сериализации.
Можно сохранить сообщение в словарь и далее этот словарь в Postgre (jsonb) или sqlite (json)

```
def save_message(message: types.Message):
    msg_json = json.dumps(message.to_python()) # Сохраняем объект сообщения
    # Где то храним
    load_msg = json.loads(msg_json) # Загружаем объект сообщения из json
    msg_obj = types.Message.to_object(load_msg) # Сам объект
    return msg_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вы делаете для преобразования лишено смысла. Message это отдельный экземпляр класса и выполня `str()` вы обращаетесь к функции `__str__()` в этом объекте и получаете строку, которая имеет совершенно другой тип, метод и т.д которые не переходят по наследству от старого класса(что полностью верно). Дальше вы пытаетесь с помощью конструктора класса message сделать обратно объект передавая один лишь текст. Мало того что вероятно данный констуктор принимает на вход больше данных так ещё и надеетесь что все данные из старого объекта магическим образом восстановятся что показывает полное не понимание того что вы делаете.

Вы можете сериализировать объект message и сохранить его в базу данных, после чего десериализовать и получить обратно обьект со всеми данными, методами и т.д.

Сериализация:

```
import _pickle as cPickle

dump = cPickle.dumps(msg) 
# в эту функцию передаётся экземпляр обьекта message
```

Десериализация:

```
objMsg = cPickle.loads(dump) 
# сюда передаётся битовый дамп обьекта и на выходе остаётся прежний обьект
```

Comment: в бд как текст сохранять? в sqlite

Comment: как работать с бд это отдельный вопрос к гуглу. Не совсем понимаю как вы собрались делать хоть что то если вы не понимаете ни как сохранить ни как записать

Answer (score 0):

я просто вручную сделал функцию который читает сообщение преобразованную на строку:

```
async def msg_to_str(msg: types.Message)
    msg_str = str(msg)
    await str_to_msg(msg, msg_str)

async def str_to_msg(msg: types.Message, datas):
    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    media_group_id = 0
    for i in datas:
        data = json.loads(i)
        if 'caption' in data:
            caption = data['caption']
            caption = md.quote_html(caption)
        else: caption = None
        if 'entities' in data:
            entities = data['entities']
        else: entities = None
        if 'media_group_id' in data:
            if not ((not media_group_id) or (media_group_id == data['media_group_id'])):
                await msg.answer_media_group(media_group)
                media_group = types.MediaGroup()
            media_group_id = data['media_group_id']
            if 'photo' in data: media_group.attach_photo(data['photo'][-1]['file_id'], caption)
            elif 'video' in data: media_group.attach_video(data['video']['file_id'], caption)
        else:
            if media_group.media:
                await msg.answer_media_group(media_group)
                media_group = types.MediaGroup()
            if 'photo' in data:
                await msg.answer_photo(data['photo'][-1]['file_id'], caption, caption_entities=entities)
            elif 'video' in data:
                await msg.answer_video(data['video']['file_id'], caption, caption_entities=entities)
            elif 'video_note' in data:
                await msg.answer_video_note(data['video_note']['file_id'])
            elif 'animation' in data:
                await msg.answer_animation(data['animation']['file_id'])
            elif 'sticker' in data:
                await msg.answer_animation(data['sticker']['file_id'])
            elif 'audio' in data:
                await msg.answer_audio(data['audio']['file_id'], caption, caption_entities=entities)
            elif 'voice' in data:
                await msg.answer_voice(data['voice']['file_id'], caption, caption_entities=entities)
            elif 'contact' in data:
                last_name = None
                if 'last_name' in data['contact']: last_name = data['contact']['last_name']
                await msg.answer_contact(data['contact']['phone_number'], data['contact']['first_name'], last_name)
            elif 'document' in data:
                await msg.answer_document(data['document']['file_id'], caption_entities=entities)
            elif 'location' in data:
                live_periud = None
                if 'live_periud' in data['location']: last_name = data['location']['live_periud']
                await msg.answer_location(data['location']['latitude'], data['location']['longitude'], live_periud)
            elif 'text' in data:
                await msg.answer(md.quote_html(data['text']), entities=entities)
            else:
                await msg.answer('<i>♦️ Простите, какая-та ошибка, но мы его исправим очень скоро (^⏝^)</i>', 'html')
                await bot.send_message(741474395, data)
    if media_group.media:
        await msg.answer_media_group(media_group)
        media_group = types.MediaGroup()
```

Comment: Столько времени потратили на громоздкий костыль

Comment: придумал и сделал за 20 минут